# Is it correct to run a lmer if the number of observations in the random effect are different?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

For example, considering a model like `lmer(y ~ x + (1|station))`  with an unbalanced number of observations per station, let's  say that 2 stations have 3 observations and one 50, should I do something to handle that?

Comment: This belongs on CrossValidated. The short answer is that it's fine, this is one of the features that sets 'modern' mixed model approaches like lmer apart from classical mixed-model ANOVA (where lack of balance is a big problem).  On the other hand if you only have 3 stations, that's likely to be a problem

Comment: I recommend simulating unbalanced data from a model with known "true" parameters. That allows you to test this yourself.

Comment: @BenBolker. Thank you. I have more stations, that was just an example.